# How can I set the default value for a Media form element?

Tags: 7, forms, media

I am using Media 2.0 and a media field in a custom admin form.

I am trying to set the default value as described on
https://www.drupal.org/project/media/issues/1158760#comment-12656764, but `#default_value = array('fid' => 1234); doesn't work.

How can I set the default value for a Media form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging in the media module, this is the working notation:

```
'#default_value' => 12345,
```

Plain and simple...